# How to move Chatter Feed of type 'TrackedChange' from contact to person account

Tags: data-loader, person-accounts, chatter-feed

We have recently adopted person account and are trying to move chatter feed from contacts to person accounts.

According to this article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213215&type=1 , we need to insert chatter feed in this case. However, feedItem with type 'TrackedChange' cannot be inserted via dataloader.

> The type of FeedItem. Except for ContentPost, LinkPost, and TextPost,
>   don’t create FeedItem types directly from the API.

So what is the normal way of handling this issue?

As requested, I post my sample anonymous block code in here:

```
FeedItem fi = new FeedItem();
fi.ParentId = '0016D00000AEjiRQAT';
fi.Type = 'TrackedChange';
fi.isRichText = false;

insert fi;
```

It still result in the same error message.

Comment: I’d suggest execute anonymous or a batch class designed for it? (That you would delete after using)

Comment: @SebastianKessel Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I tried execute anonymous but doesn't seem to work very well as well. Got the same error message. Do you want me to post the sample apex code?

Comment: Code could make it easier to get help. Make sure you ExecAnon from the Dev Console. If not, try with an apex class in a sandbox. Exec Anon in an IDE could be using an API to execute.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I executed in developer console, which I believe is also using API to execute as well. Regardless, I got the same error. Code posted as requested.

Comment: You should save this inside of a class and try. That won’t use an API

Comment: Then use a vf page to call it? @SebastianKessel

Comment: That’s a choice. Or even  try running the class via Exec Anon. Or, if its a large volume, make it a batch job and schedule it.

Comment: @SebastianKessel Actually I just tried with VF page with a custom controller since it is not too hard... But getting the same error: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD, Cannot directly insert FeedItem with type TrackedChange: [Type]. So this is not simply API, Salesforce is just blocking it.